# Heroku web workers timeout caused by worker

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a problem with a process in an app of mine hosted on Heroku (2xweb + 1x worder dynos). The process ends with quite a heavy email being created and sent via SendGrid. This took some time, causing web worker timeouts and bad usability, so it was refactored into a worker, which I thought would solve the problem, but I'm getting situations like this:

```
Apr 10 17:12:48 wc heroku/web.2:  Processing by DealsController#show as */* 
[request is processed]
Apr 10 17:12:50 wc app/worker.1:  [worker sending emails] 
[a lot of lines with debug data cut]
Apr 10 17:12:53 wc heroku/worker.1:  source=worker.1 dyno=heroku.16079351.858a3455-0b9f-4f75-9052-b419d4653703 sample#load_avg_1m=0.29 sample#load_avg_5m=0.07 sample#load_avg_15m=0.02 
Apr 10 17:12:53 wc heroku/worker.1:  source=worker.1 dyno=heroku.16079351.858a3455-0b9f-4f75-9052-b419d4653703 sample#memory_total=240.45MB sample#memory_rss=240.34MB sample#memory_cache=0.11MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=85990pages sample#memory_pgpgout=24436pages 
Apr 10 17:12:53 wc heroku/web.2:  source=web.2 dyno=heroku.16079351.879182ef-13f0-4908-bf35-c487ccab6153 sample#load_avg_1m=0.00 sample#load_avg_5m=0.01 sample#load_avg_15m=0.01 
Apr 10 17:12:54 wc heroku/web.2:  source=web.2 dyno=heroku.16079351.879182ef-13f0-4908-bf35-c487ccab6153 sample#memory_total=844.16MB sample#memory_rss=511.82MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=332.34MB sample#memory_pgpgin=223581pages sample#memory_pgpgout=92554pages 
Apr 10 17:12:54 wc heroku/web.2:  Process running mem=844M(164.9%) 
Apr 10 17:12:54 wc heroku/web.2:  Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) 
Apr 10 17:12:54 wc app/web.2:  ** [NewRelic][04/10/14 15:12:54 +0000 879182ef-13f0-4908-bf35-c487ccab6153 (468)] INFO : Starting Agent shutdown 
Apr 10 17:12:55 wc app/worker.1:  ** [Bugsnag] Bugsnag exception handler 1.6.2 ready, api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[8 new relic lines cut]
Apr 10 17:12:56 wc app/heroku-postgres:  source=HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE sample#current_transaction=144542 sample#db_size=189720760bytes sample#tables=92 sample#active-connections=12 sample#waiting-connections=0 sample#index-cache-hit-rate=0.99981 sample#table-cache-hit-rate=0.99868 sample#load-avg-1m=0.36 sample#load-avg-5m=0.3 sample#load-avg-15m=0.285 sample#read-iops=38.367 sample#write-iops=13.221 sample#memory-total=7629464kB sample#memory-free=187884kB sample#memory-cached=6599816kB sample#memory-postgres=689216kB 
Apr 10 17:12:56 wc app/worker.1:  ** [NewRelic][04/10/14 15:12:55 +0000 858a3455-0b9f-4f75-9052-b419d4653703 (99)] INFO : Installing DelayedJob instrumentation hooks 
[11 new relic lines cut] 
Apr 10 17:12:59 wc app/worker.1:    Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (1.6ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2014-04-10 15:12:59.482734', locked_by = 'host:858a3455-0b9f-4f75-9052-b419d4653703 pid:2' WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2014-04-10 15:12:59.481969' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2014-04-10 11:12:59.482002') OR locked_by = 'host:858a3455-0b9f-4f75-9052-b419d4653703 pid:2') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING * 
Apr 10 17:12:59 wc app/worker.1:  ** [NewRelic][04/10/14 15:12:59 +0000 858a3455-0b9f-4f75-9052-b419d4653703 (99)] INFO : Starting Agent shutdown 
Apr 10 17:13:09 wc app/worker.1:    Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (1.6ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2014-04-10 15:13:09.486147', locked_by = 'host:858a3455-0b9f-4f75-9052-b419d4653703 pid:2' WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2014-04-10 15:13:09.485453' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2014-04-10 11:13:09.485486') OR locked_by = 'host:858a3455-0b9f-4f75-9052-b419d4653703 pid:2') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING * 
Apr 10 17:13:13 wc heroku/web.2:  source=web.2 dyno=heroku.16079351.879182ef-13f0-4908-bf35-c487ccab6153 sample#load_avg_1m=0.00 sample#load_avg_5m=0.01 sample#load_avg_15m=0.01 
Apr 10 17:13:14 wc heroku/web.2:  source=web.2 dyno=heroku.16079351.879182ef-13f0-4908-bf35-c487ccab6153 sample#memory_total=463.75MB sample#memory_rss=153.29MB sample#memory_cache=0.00MB sample#memory_swap=310.46MB sample#memory_pgpgin=245188pages sample#memory_pgpgout=205946pages 
Apr 10 17:13:14 wc app/web.2:  Started GET "/user" for [IP.IP.IP.IP] at 2014-04-10 15:13:13 +0000 
Apr 10 17:13:14 wc heroku/worker.1:  source=worker.1 dyno=heroku.16079351.858a3455-0b9f-4f75-9052-b419d4653703 sample#load_avg_1m=0.21 sample#load_avg_5m=0.06 sample#load_avg_15m=0.02 
Apr 10 17:13:14 wc heroku/worker.1:  source=worker.1 dyno=heroku.16079351.858a3455-0b9f-4f75-9052-b419d4653703 sample#memory_total=157.25MB sample#memory_rss=157.14MB sample#memory_cache=0.11MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=103179pages sample#memory_pgpgout=62923pages 
Apr 10 17:13:16 wc app/web.2:  Started GET "/user" for [IP.IP.IP.IP] at 2014-04-10 15:13:16 +0000 
Apr 10 17:13:17 wc heroku/router:  at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path=/pages/planning host=www.cool-app.com request_id=c62a7ee5-11d8-4286-846a-a55861cc6a0e fwd="[IP.IP.IP.IP]" dyno=web.2 connect=2ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 
Apr 10 17:13:19 wc app/web.2:  E, [2014-04-10T15:13:18.948990 #2] ERROR -- : worker=1 PID:12 timeout (31s > 30s), killing 
Apr 10 17:13:19 wc app/worker.1:    Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (1.5ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2014-04-10 15:13:19.489494', locked_by = 'host:858a3455-0b9f-4f75-9052-b419d4653703 pid:2' WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2014-04-10 15:13:19.488845' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2014-04-10 11:13:19.488874') OR locked_by = 'host:858a3455-0b9f-4f75-9052-b419d4653703 pid:2') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING * 
Apr 10 17:13:20 wc app/web.2:  E, [2014-04-10T15:13:19.689336 #2] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 12 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=1 
Apr 10 17:13:21 wc app/web.2:  Disconnected from ActiveRecord 
Apr 10 17:13:27 wc app/web.2:  Processing by UsersController#show as HTML 
[web worker 2 works properly from now on]
```

The web.2 worker still crashes resulting in a ~20 second hang for the user and and "Application Error" screen being shown. What's strange is that this happens on different pages and seems to be linked to the worker in the background.

The line that especially confuses me (and the one probably symptomatic of the crash) is:

```
Apr 10 17:13:19 wc app/web.2:  E, [2014-04-10T15:13:18.948990 #2] ERROR -- : worker=1 PID:12 timeout (31s > 30s), killing
```

What does it mean? It seems to me that the web.2 dyno is being killed because the worker=1 had a timout, which seems a bit crazy.

The configuration for the dynos is:
[image: Dyno config]

```
Dynos:
1x - 2 - web bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
1x - 1 - worker bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Unicorn, in which case the `worker` there is referring to a Unicorn worker?

Comment: @catsby I don't think so - it's just a rake task - I updated the question with the Dyno config so you can be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: switch from `delayed_job` to `sidekiq`

To whom it may concern - despite several hours of debugging, I was never really able to get to the bottom of this. Decided to try switching this one job over to `sidekiq`. This solved the issue. Probably just a bug with the particular delayed_job -> heroku interaction. Maybe this would be working today...